# ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed

Tags: python, numpy

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
daal4py 2021.5.0 requires daal==2021.4.0, which is not installed.
mxnet 1.7.0.post2 requires numpy<1.17.0,>=1.8.2, but you have numpy 1.18.5 which is incompatible.
d2l 0.17.5 requires numpy==1.21.5, but you have numpy 1.18.5 which is incompatible.
d2l 0.17.5 requires requests==2.25.1, but you have requests 2.18.4 which is incompatible.
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: ok, so what is the question here?

Answer (score 20):

Try adding `--use-deprecated=legacy-resolver` after your pip install commands
for example:

> !pip install -r
> requirements.txt --use-deprecated=legacy-resolver

Comment: To help understand what this is doing, I found this link useful: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/dependency-resolution/

Answer (score 9):

Below solution worked for me:

Before you install your extension, just follow the prompts

```
pip install h5py
pip install typing-extensions
pip install wheel
```

and then install your extension

Thanks to the source.
source: https://github.com/apple/turicreate/issues/3383#issuecomment-1010006358

Answer (score 0):

There are compatibility issues between the versions of your installed packages. To fix this you have to uninstall the ones that are not compatible, and install those who are.

Run in terminal:

```
pip uninstall daal==2021.5.0
pip install daal==2021.4.0
pip uninstall numpy==1.18.5
pip install numpy==1.8.2
pip install numpy==1.21.5
pip uninstall requests==2.18.4
pip install requests==2.25.1
```

Note: you can check all the packages and dependencies in your environment by running:

```
pip freeze
```